# NSIS code to check for at least Windows 10 and X64

Tags: nsis

I've added a .OnInit function to my installer script:

```
    Function .onInit
    ${IfNot} ${AtLeastWin10}
      MessageBox mb_iconStop "Windows 10 x64 is required to install DeepSkyStacker 5.1.0"
      Abort
    ${EndIf}
    ${IfNot} ${RunningX64}
      MessageBox mb_iconStop "Windows 10 x64 is required to install DeepSkyStacker 5.1.0"
      Abort
    ${EndIf}
    FunctionEnd
```

Can the two tests be combined? It seems a bit clumsy as it is ...

Thanks
David

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question but it must be as an answer, not an edit in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like:

```
Function .onInit
${IfNot} ${AtLeastWin10}
${OrIfNot} ${RunningX64}
    MessageBox mb_iconStop "Windows 10 x64 is required to install DeepSkyStacker 5.1.0"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Should do it!